# Decomposing a metric tree as a union of rooted (or "centered") trees

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, trees

Suppose $G$ is a finite metric tree whose set of leaves is $A=\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$. Consider the function $G\to \mathbb R_+$ that assigns to a point $x$ the distance from $x$ to $A$, denoted $d(x, A)$. Let $m_1, \ldots, m_l$ be the points of $G$ where this function attains a local maximum. I claim it is a non-empty finite discrete subset of $G$. $l=1$ if an only if $G$ has a point that is equidistanced from all points of $A$. I call such trees "centered" - this is similar to being a "rooted" tree.

For each $i=1, \ldots, l$, let $T_i$ be the union of paths from $m_i$ to those elements $v_j\in A$ that satisfy $d(v_j, m_i)\le d(v_k, m_i)$ for all $k=1, \ldots, n$. I claim that $T_1, \ldots, T_l$ defines a canonical decomposition of $G$ as a  union of maximal centered trees.

My question is: Does this decomposition have a name? Has it been studied or used for something? I am also interested in extensions of this construction to the case when $G$ is a general metric graph with marked points.